# Are public saunas linked to gay culture in England?

Tags: culture, england

During my stay in Liverpool, England I was looking for a sauna and conducted a search "Liverpool sauna" on Google. [Splash Sauna Liverpool](https://web.archive.org/web/20161110174434/http://www.splashsauna.com/) was the first hit, no other saunas on the first search results page. Apart from the muscular male photo on the front page and maybe "discrete location and entrance", nothing on the front page points to a gay club. When browsing to the [facilities tab](https://web.archive.org/web/20161110174536/http://www.splashsauna.com/Facilities.aspx) the place's nature becomes evident:

> - Fun room with large communal round bed
> - Maze, cell, sling, St Andrews cross, kneeling bench and glory holes

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it seems to me that an answer surveying those differences would not need to be overly long or confusing.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: OK, but does gay culture differ a lot between European countries? I'm already disappointed for having to narrow down the scope of my question.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, I'm afraid. Qs here should be about [actual problems you face](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) so if you travel to e.g. UK and wonder about the situation there, make the Q about UK. Because it is completely different from the one in Finnland, Germany or Italy and a good A would need to be a huge list or you get a huge number of As that are hard to navigate. Narrow it down to one country and you have a great Q. And you can ask more Qs for other countries if you consider visiting there (but better one at a time). Also yes, gay culture differs hugely.

Comment: @mts The new version of the question is probably better but I am not sure a good answer to a broader question would necessarily be a long list. You could easily structure it the other way around, with a paragraph for countries where saunas are strongly associated with gay culture, another one for countries where sauna are popular across the board, etc.

Comment: *Apart from the muscular male photo on the front page and maybe "discrete location and entrance", nothing on the homepage points to a gay club"* - that's obvious giveaway. Google regular saunas in your country, I'm sure none of them presents itself this way :)

Comment: @phoog I have only visited saunas in a handful of European countries and find the culture and etiquette differences even between 'normal' saunas in those few countries confusing enough. Within Germany, you will even find significant cultural differences between different parts of Germany.

Comment: If you want to find an actual sauna, probably better looking for a sports centre, or health club, or spa.

Comment: It's hard to think of a more un-British concept than a public sauna.

Answer (score 9):

> Are public saunas linked to gay culture in the UK?

If by *public* you mean clubs and the like, then yes. Taking Manchester as an example (you seem to know about Liverpool) a Google search *manchester sauna* selects 5 - 4 described with "Sauna" one "Adult Entertainment Club". Of the four, two advertise themselves as gay clubs. The other two seem more like 'massage parlours'.

Comment: And by private I mean saunas people have on their homes, over three million saunas in Finland alone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_sauna

Comment: @user598527 That’s only like 60 % of the population. I would have expected more!

Answer (score 9):

Saunas in the UK are typically found in one of two places: Health/Fitness/Sports Clubs/Spas with swimming pools (places like Bannatynes, University sports centres etc.), and "Gay" saunas which are more oriented towards homosexual acts. If you want to just visit a normal sauna, there are plenty of places, you typically can also use the other facilites in the swimming pool area.

Bear in mind in the former it is **not** customary to remove garments when entering the sauna (unlike in many European countries), in fact it is pretty much forbidden in most places.

Comment: "Bear in mind in the former it is not customary to remove garments when entering the sauna (unlike in many European countries), in fact it is pretty much forbidden in most places." Does this apply to washroom? In swimming pool I visited other men washed swimming trunks on.

Comment: @user598527 No, you can take them off in the changing room, some wash with them on but it's not required. Outside of the changing rooms nudity is generally not allowed.

Comment: Do you live in England? Have you encountered many "gay saunas"?

Comment: @user598527 I know of some, yes, I work near a gay district. Not being of that orientation I haven't been in.